# Python: How to run unittest.main() for all source files in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am developing a Python module with several source files, each with its own test class derived from [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) right in the source.  Consider the directory structure:

```
dirFoo\
    test.py
    dirBar\
        __init__.py
        Foo.py
        Bar.py
```

To test either Foo.py or Bar.py, I would add this at the end of the Foo.py and Bar.py source files:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And run Python on either source, i.e.

```
$ python Foo.py
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 2.314s

OK
```

Ideally, I would have "test.py" automagically search dirBar for any unittest derived classes and make one call to "unittest.main()".  What's the best way to do this in practice?

I tried using Python to call [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) for every *.py file in dirBar, which runs once for the first .py file found & exits the calling test.py, plus then I have to duplicate my code by adding unittest.main() in every source file--which violates DRY principles.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I knew there was an obvious solution:

```
dirFoo\
    __init__.py
    test.py
    dirBar\
        __init__.py
        Foo.py
        Bar.py
```

Contents of dirFoo/test.py

```
from dirBar import *
import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.main()
```

Run the tests:

```
$ python test.py
...........
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 11 tests in 2.305s

OK
```

Comment: Either you've missed 'dirBar/__init__.py` or `from dirBar import *` won't work. btw, use lowercase for package/module names.

Comment: Also, the problem with this is that you assume the test cases of Foo.py and Bar.py are exposed in the dirBar __init__.py module. If they're not, your test.py won't test anything.

Comment: So 7 years later, I figure someone might as well add the init, since no one else will.

Comment: Please show what your `dirBar/__init__.py` looks like.

Comment: I don't know if this is what the author intended, but the way I got it to work is instead of "from dirBar import *" I did "from dirBar.Foo import *" and "from dirBar.Bar import *" and the __init__.,py is an empty file that tells python that directory should be treated as a package.

Answer (score 65):

As of Python 2.7, test discovery is automated in the unittest package. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html):

> Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible
>   with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages
>   importable from the top-level directory of the project (this means
>   that their filenames must be valid identifiers).
>
> Test discovery is implemented in `TestLoader.discover()`, but can also
>   be used from the command line. The basic command-line usage is:
>
> ```
> cd project_directory
> python -m unittest discover
> ```

By default it looks for packages named `test*.py`, but this can be changed so you might use something like

```
python -m unittest discover --pattern=*.py
```

In place of your test.py script.

Comment: is pattern the only way to select a restricted set of test to run ?
I am having issue with test running fine using discovery but failing when i want to run individual tests due to path issues.

Comment: any suggestion for python 2.6 ?

Comment: @larrycai either see the other answers here, or check out unittest2 http://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

Answer (score 38):

Here is my test discovery code that seems to do the job. I wanted to make sure I can extend the tests easily without having to list them in any of the involved files, but also avoid writing all tests in one single Übertest file.

So the structure is

```
myTests.py
testDir\
    __init__.py
    testA.py
    testB.py
```

myTest.py look like this:

```
import unittest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(testsuite)
```

I believe this is the simplest solution for writing several test cases in one directory. The solution requires Python 2.7 or Python 3.

Answer (score 18):

You should try [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It's a library to help create tests and it integrates with `unittest` or `doctest`. All you need to do is run `nosetests` and it'll find all your unittests for you.

```
% nosetests # finds all tests in all subdirectories
% nosetests tests/ # find all tests in the tests directory
```

Comment: The question explicitly asked about solutions using unittest

Comment: It may be beneficial to explain any immediate benefits of using nosetests that might be related to the questions' intent? Especially since this question asks about unittest specifically.

Answer (score 4):

In case it happens to help anyone, here is the approach I arrived at for solving this problem. I had the use case where I have the following directory structure:

```
mypackage/
    tests/
        test_category_1/
            tests_1a.py
            tests_1b.py
            ...
        test_category_2/
            tests_2a.py
            tests_2b.py
            ...
        ...
```

and I want all of the following to work in the obvious way and to be able to be supplied the same commandline arguments as are accepted by unittest:

```
python -m mypackage.tests
python -m mypackage.tests.test_category_1
python -m mypackage.tests.test_category_1.tests_1a
```

The solution was to set up `mypackage/tests/__init__.py` like this:

```
import unittest

def prepare_load_tests_function (the__path__):
    test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(the__path__[0])
    def load_tests (_a, _b, _c):
        return test_suite
    return load_tests
```

and to set up `mypackage/tests/__main__.py` like this:

```
import unittest
from . import prepare_load_tests_function, __path__

load_tests = prepare_load_tests_function(__path__)
unittest.main()
```

and to copy and paste an empty `__init__.py` and the following `__main__.py` in each `mypackage/tests/test_category_n/`:

```
import unittest
from .. import prepare_load_tests_function
from . import __path__

load_tests = prepare_load_tests_function(__path__)
unittest.main()
```

and also to add the standard `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` in each actual tests file.

(Works for me on Python 3.3 on Windows, ymmv.)

Comment: +1 for utilizing the discover API directly, which supports situations where we don't have control of the python cmd

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a snippet that may do what you want. It walks a path that you provide looking for Python packages/modules and accumulates a set of test suites from those modules, which it then executes all at once.

The nice thing about this is that it will work on all packages nested under the directory you specify, and you won't have to manually change the imports as you add new components.

```
import logging
import os
import unittest

MODULE_EXTENSIONS = set('.py .pyc .pyo'.split())

def unit_test_extractor(tup, path, filenames):
    """Pull ``unittest.TestSuite``s from modules in path
    if the path represents a valid Python package. Accumulate
    results in `tup[1]`.
    """
    package_path, suites = tup
    logging.debug('Path: %s', path)
    logging.debug('Filenames: %s', filenames)
    relpath = os.path.relpath(path, package_path)
    relpath_pieces = relpath.split(os.sep)

    if relpath_pieces[0] == '.': # Base directory.
        relpath_pieces.pop(0) # Otherwise, screws up module name.
    elif not any(os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, '__init__' + ext))
            for ext in MODULE_EXTENSIONS):
        return # Not a package directory and not the base directory, reject.

    logging.info('Base: %s', '.'.join(relpath_pieces))
    for filename in filenames:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext not in MODULE_EXTENSIONS: # Not a Python module.
            continue
        logging.info('Module: %s', base)
        module_name = '.'.join(relpath_pieces + [base])
        logging.info('Importing from %s', module_name)
        module = __import__(module_name)
        module_suites = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromModule(module)
        logging.info('Got suites: %s', module_suites)
        suites += module_suites

def get_test_suites(path):
    """:return: Iterable of suites for the packages/modules
    present under :param:`path`.
    """
    logging.info('Base path: %s', package_path)
    suites = []
    os.path.walk(package_path, unit_test_extractor, (package_path, suites))
    logging.info('Got suites: %s', suites)
    return suites

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
    package_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    suites = get_test_suites(package_path)
    for suite in suites:
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: I think that your `get_test_suites(path)` in fact needs to be `get_test_suites(package_path)`.