# Common convention for invoking unit tests across a python project?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

Is there a standard convention, or even a growing one, around where and how to invoke the tests associated with a project? In many projects, I'm seeing it bundled into a Make, a separate test.py script at the top level of the project, etc to do the work.

I looked around for some common thing with setup.py, but didn't spot anything there (granted, I didn't look hard). What's common and best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, there's a simple convention built-in to the unittest module. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644821/python-how-to-run-unittest-main-for-all-source-files-in-a-subdirectory).

Comment: Why not this: `import x; x.test()`? Pardon the semicolon.

Comment: If you read my link, you'll see how the unittest module does that for you.

Comment: So the convention is to put a test.py at the root of your project that does all the relevant imports and invokes them with unittest.main() ?

Comment: @heckj, Yes, assuming all your unittest-containing files are structured as a Python package accessible from test.py.