# Recursive unittest discover

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I have a package with a directory "tests" in which I'm storing my unit tests. My package looks like:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── models
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── tc.py
├── tests
│   ├── db
│   │   └── test_employee.py
│   └── test_tc.py
└── todo.txt
```

From my package directory, I want to be able to find both `tests/test_tc.py` and `tests/db/test_employee.py`. I'd prefer not to have to install a third-party library (`nose` or etc) or have to manually build a `TestSuite` to run this in.

Surely there's a way to tell `unittest discover` not to stop looking once it's found a test? `python -m unittest discover -s tests` will find `tests/test_tc.py` and `python -m unittest discover -s tests/db` will find `tests/db/test_employee.py`. Isn't there a way to find both?

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/644821/3001761? I think some of those answers could be adapted for your purposes.

Comment: Solution which does not requires creation of `__init__.py` files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155753/4669135

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In doing a bit of digging, it seems that as long as deeper modules remain importable, they'll be discovered via `python -m unittest discover`. The solution, then, was simply to add a `__init__.py` file to each directory to make them packages.

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── models
│   └── __init__.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── tc.py
├── tests
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── __init__.py       # NEW
│   │   └── test_employee.py
│   ├── __init__.py           # NEW
│   └── test_tc.py
└── todo.txt
```

So long as each directory has an `__init__.py`, `python -m unittest discover` can import the relevant `test_*` module.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work either. What do you put in your __init__.py for this to work?

Comment: @Chuck the diagram in the answer shows the `# NEW` files. Make sure that your _whole_ directory structure is importable (so in this case, `import tests`, `import tests.test_tc`, `import tests.db` and `import tests.db.test_employee` are all valid)

Answer (score 7):

If you're okay with adding a `__init__.py` file inside tests, you can put a `load_tests` function there that will handle discovery for you.

> If a test package name (directory with `__init__.py`) matches the
>           pattern then the package will be checked for a 'load_tests' function. If
>           this exists then it will be called with loader, tests, pattern.
>
> If load_tests exists then discovery does  *not* recurse into the package,
>           load_tests is responsible for loading all tests in the package.

I'm far from confident that this is the best way, but one way to write that function would be:

```
import os
import pkgutil
import inspect
import unittest

# Add *all* subdirectories to this module's path
__path__ = [x[0] for x in os.walk(os.path.dirname(__file__))]

def load_tests(loader, suite, pattern):
    for imp, modname, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
        mod = imp.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)
        for memname, memobj in inspect.getmembers(mod):
            if inspect.isclass(memobj):
                if issubclass(memobj, unittest.TestCase):
                    print("Found TestCase: {}".format(memobj))
                    for test in loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(memobj):
                        print("  Found Test: {}".format(test))
                        suite.addTest(test)

    print("=" * 70)
    return suite
```

Pretty ugly, I agree.

First you add all subdirectories to the test packages's path ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories)).

Then, you use [`pkgutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) to walk the path, looking for packages or modules.

When it finds one, it then checks the module members to see whether they're classes, and if they're classes, whether they're subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`.  If they are, the tests inside the classes are loaded into the test suite.

So now, from inside your project root, you can type

```
python -m unittest discover -p tests
```

Using the `-p` pattern switch.  If all goes well, you'll see what I saw, which is something like:

```
Found TestCase: <class 'test_tc.TestCase'>
  Found Test: testBar (test_tc.TestCase)
  Found Test: testFoo (test_tc.TestCase)
Found TestCase: <class 'test_employee.TestCase'>
  Found Test: testBar (test_employee.TestCase)
  Found Test: testFoo (test_employee.TestCase)
======================================================================
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Which is what was expected, each of my two example files contained two tests, `testFoo` and `testBar` each.

**Edit:** After some more digging, it looks like you could specify this function as:

```
def load_tests(loader, suite, pattern):
    for imp, modname, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
        mod = imp.find_module(modname).load_module(modname)
        for test in loader.loadTestsFromModule(mod):
            print("Found Tests: {}".format(test._tests))
            suite.addTests(test)
```

This uses the `loader.loadTestsFromModule()` method instead of the `loader.loadTestsFromTestCase()` method I used above.  It still modifies the `tests` package path and walks it looking for modules, which I think is the key here.

The output looks a bit different now, since we're adding a found testsuite at a time to our main testsuite `suite`:

```
python -m unittest discover -p tests
Found Tests: [<test_tc.TestCase testMethod=testBar>, <test_tc.TestCase testMethod=testFoo>]
Found Tests: [<test_employee.TestCase testMethod=testBar>, <test_employee.TestCase testMethod=testFoo>]
======================================================================
....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But we still get the 4 tests we expected, in both classes, in both subdirectories.

Comment: This is massively harder than `python -m unittest discover -s tests --recursive`, which is what I was REALLY hoping someone would snarkily comment before voting to close. (that is to say, *thank you!*)

Comment: @AdamSmith no problem, I hope it helps -- after a bit of digging, there looks to be a method that is a bit simpler, relying more on the unittest discovery than the explicit checking I had -- I'll edit my answer to include this alternative.

Comment: Hmm there's a yet easier way I just accidentally discovered. I'll self-answer, though yours is still more foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

The point using **init**.py, is that one may encounters side effects, like **file** not being the script file path. Using FOR DOS command can help (not found of DOS commands, but sometimes it helps

```
setlocal
set CWD=%CD%
FOR /R %%T in (*_test.py) do (
  CD %%~pT
  python %%T
)
CD %CWD%
endlocal
```

- /R allows for walkthrough the hierarchy from current folder.
- (expr) allows for selecting test files (I use _test.py)
- %%~pT is $(dirname $T) in shell.
- I saved and restore my original directory, as the .bat leaves me where it ends
- setlocal ... endlocal to not pollute my environment with CWD.