# Recursive unittest discovery with python3 and without __init__.py files

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have project with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── requirements.txt
├── main.py
├── tests
    ├── unit
    │   └── test_thing1.py
    │   └── test_thing2.py
    └── integration
        └── test_integration_thing1.py
        └── test_integration_thing2.py
```

**I want to run all tests with one command**. If I do `python -m unittest discover`, no tests are executed.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713541/recursive-unittest-discover) that suggest adding a `__init__.py` file to make packages out of the `unit` and `integration` folders. The solution works, and all tests are running this way.

But since I'm using python3 and `__init__.py` files are not required with [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), I was wondering if there was a way to make this works without those `__init__.py` files.

Comment: seems related [bug#17457](https://bugs.python.org/issue17457) which was fixed in python 3.4. which version of python you are using?

Answer (score 9):

I looked into it, and think its most likely a bug.

So I created a [python bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue35617) and a [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/11364) which fixes the issue for me.

Clone it and see if it works for you as well, with the fix the best way of running discover was `python -m unittest discover -s tests`. Otherwise it will look in for example virtual environments that are below the top dir.

Comment: 5 years after the [original bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue23882) and `unittest` is still broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that namespace package is regular package.
You must not expect namespace package is treated same to regular package.

Read this article too.
https://dev.to/methane/don-t-omit-init-py-3hga

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the point of forcing the creation of `__init__.py` in each subdirectory, at least in my case: I am testing a Python wrapper of C++ code, so I am not testing a Python module that I have implemented. Also there is a risk that I will forget to create some `__init__.py` files which would lead to silently skipped tests.

So here is a solution to not have to create `__init__.py` in each subdirectory:

```
import glob
import os
import unittest

def test_suite_from_recursive_discover(pattern):
    test_files = glob.glob('**/{}'.format(pattern), recursive=True)
    test_dirs = list(set(([os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(test_file)) for test_file in test_files])))

    suites = [unittest.TestLoader().discover(start_dir=d, pattern=pattern) for d in test_dirs]
    suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites)
    return suite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test_suite_from_recursive_discover('test*.py'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use pytest. It does discover tests in folders.

In your case you just need to install in via pip (`pip install pytest`) and then run in your root folder `pytest tests`.