# Python 2.6.6 unittest test discovery

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-unittest

There are lots of answers for test discovery in python 2.7+ but I need one for python 2.6.6.

I've got such directory structure:

```
root
|-- runall.py
|-- src
|   |-- a.py
|   |-- b.py
|-- test
    |-- atest.py
    |-- btest.py
```

I would like to load all tests from `test` in `runall.py` and run them with `unittest.main()`. How can I achieve that in python 2.6.6 (**without installing additional modules!**) in most elegant way ?

Comment: Can you use [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2)? It has the functionality of `unittest` in Python 2.7, backported to Python 2.4+.

Comment: I don't have `unittest2`

Comment: You're not able to install it?

Comment: I am unable + I don't want to as far as this one is deployed across the globe on various python 2.6 env's. If it were so easy, I wouldn't 've asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate from: [Python: How to run unittest.main() for all source files in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644821/python-how-to-run-unittest-main-for-all-source-files-in-a-subdirectory)

You should try using nosetests: https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/  It is a pretty easy module for running all your tests.  We use it a lot at work:

Here is the answer from the other post, kind of hackish, but appears to work.

```
dirFoo\
    test.py
    dirBar\
        Foo.py
        Bar.py
```

Contents of dirFoo/test.py

```
from dirBar import *
import unittest

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Not working: `Ran 0 tests in 0.000s`. Also, I can't install any modules + I don't want to.