# Python 3.7 Unit Tests

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, subdirectory, relative-import

So I tried many things (from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644821/python-how-to-run-unittest-main-for-all-source-files-in-a-subdirectory) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory) more) getting my tests running but nothing worked this is my current code:

`test.py` which I call to run the tests: `python3 ./src/preprocess/python/test.py`
    import unittest

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testsuite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('.')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(testsuite)
```

the test file looks like this:

```
import unittest
from scrapes.pdf import full_path_to_destination_txt_file

print(full_path_to_destination_txt_file)

class PreprocessingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def path_txt_appending(self):
        self.assertEqual(full_path_to_destination_txt_file(
            "test", "/usr/test"), "/usr/test/test.txt")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

But the output is always like this:

```
python3 ./src/preprocess/python/test.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Additional Information:

- As you can see I call this not from my root directory. The test folder is in `./src/preprocess/python/test/` and has a `__init__.py`file included (there is also a init file on the level of test.py)
- it would be okay for me if I have to code down all the calls for all the tests I just want to finish this
- automatic search with -t does not work either so I thought the more robust method here with test.py would work...
- using this framework is a requirement I have to follow
- test_preprocessing.py is in the test folder and `from scrapes.pdf import full_path_to_destination_txt_file`scrapes is a module folder on the same level as test
- When I call the single unit test directly in the command line it fails because of the relative import. But using the test.py (obviously) finds the modules.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

By default, unittest will only execute methods whose name starts with `test`:

> **testMethodPrefix**
>
> String giving the prefix of method names which will be interpreted as test methods. The default value is 'test'.
>   This affects getTestCaseNames() and all the loadTestsFrom*() methods.

from the [docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix)

Either change that attribute or (preferably) prefix your method name with `test_`.